# kubernetes mountPath vs hostPath

Tags: kubernetes

I am trying to deploy an app to kubernetes cluster and I want to store data in **Persistent Volume**. However, I am very confused about two parameters in the setup. Can someone explains what is the different between **volumes.hostPath** and **volumeMounts.mountPath**? I read some documentations online but it does not help me to understand.

```
volumeMounts:
  - mountPath: /var/lib/mysql

volumes:
  hostPath:
    path: /k8s
```

If my setup is as above, is the volume going to be mounted at `/k8s/var/lib/mysql`?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The mount path is always the destination inside the Pod a volume gets mounted to.

I think the documentation is pretty clear on what hostPath does:

> A hostPath volume mounts a file or directory from the host node’s
>   filesystem into your Pod. This is not something that most Pods will
>   need, but it offers a powerful escape hatch for some applications.
>
> For example, some uses for a hostPath are:
>
> ```
> - running a Container that needs access to Docker internals; use a hostPath of /var/lib/docker
> - running cAdvisor in a Container; use a hostPath of /sys
> - allowing a Pod to specify whether a given hostPath should exist prior to the Pod running, whether it should be created, and what it should exist as
> ```

So your example does not what you think it does. It would mount the node's `/k8s` directory into the Pod at `/var/lib/mysql`.

This should be done only if you fully understand the implications!

Comment: It would be nice to provide a [link](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#hostpath) to the mentioned documentation page.

Comment: And what are those “implications?”

Comment: The data is local to the node and that might eliminate some of the benefits of Kubernetes and usually they are only useful for specific needs. For example rescheduling a pod to a different node means the data is not moving with it. The data might be seen by a different pod on the same node. There is no particular management of persistence or the life cycle of the volume/data. In case all of those are fine you should still think about alternatives like `emptyDir` first.

Answer (score 14):

**Host path:** The directory in your node. 
**Mount path:** The directory in your pod.

Your setup will mount the node's directory(`/k8s`) into the pod's directory(at `/var/lib/mysql`)

Comment: Are you sure.  ?

Comment: yes, I'm sure...

Comment: al right.......